# Problem while parsing and recognising html tags using BeautifulSoap in Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a block of html code. I need to take Name 1 and Name 2 and links from this code separately. As a result I want dictionary.

```
{"red" : {"name" : Name1, url: "http://link1.com"}, "blue": {"name" : Name2, "url": "http://link2.com"}}
```

But in this code I can't understand how I can catch Name2 and link2

I'm using Python and Beautiful soap with Requests lib
Could you please help me, thank you.

```
    <td style="width:100px" class="b-fight-details__table-col l-page_align_left">
      
          <p class="b-fight-details__table-text">

            <a class="b-link b-link_style_black" href="http://link1.com">
              Name 1
            </a>

          </p>

          <p class="b-fight-details__table-text">

            <a class="b-link b-link_style_black" href="http://link2.com">
              Name 2
            </a>
          </p>
```

Comment: Please edit the code of your attempt into your question.

Comment: @barny ok done, please up question

Comment: @FedorPetrenko Please share your code so it will be better for understanding!

Comment: You didn’t put any code to try solve this into your question, so no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import requests    

html = requests.get(yoururl).text
yourdict = {}
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for a in soup.find_all('a', class_="b-link b-link_style_black"):
    print("Name:", a.text, "\n link:" a['href'])
    yourdict['red'] = {'name':a.text, 'link':a['href']}
```